# How do i get a list of all users, passwords and groups from an activeDirectory using System.DirectoryServices?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to get a list of all users, passwords and groups from an activeDirectory. I use System.DirectoryServices. How do I do this?

edit: How do I get all groups a specific user belongs too?

Comment: You probably cant get the passwords

Comment: To get the passwords you would need an attack vector on the password hashes stored in AD, these are not accesible through `DirectoryServices`, then you would need lots of computing power and a brute force attack or you would need to crack the hashing algorithm, none of these requirements are trivial. For the bits you are allowed to know, see the answers below.

Comment: Simple solution.  Using an Administrator account change the password for each user to something you know.  This way you don't have to "retrieve" the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx), using filters like "(objectClass=user)" and  "(objectClass=group)".

You cannot get the passwords, anyway. That would be a huge security flaw...